# Nested loop output confusion

Tags: python, loops, nested, nested-loops

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print(i, j, end='')
```

Hey guys so im just having problems understanding this concept of nested loops.
The output when I run the program is: 0 00 11 01 1

I cant figure out why the output is the way it is. Could anybody give me a step by step explanation of the order in which this is executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops in your program. One is outer and another one is inner loop.
So this is how code is working.
First of all following code is executed

```
for i in range(2):
```

This puts value 0 in i.
Now it enters to inner loop. So following code is executed

```
for j in range(2):
```

This puts value 0 in j.
Now the following code executes

```
print(i,j,end='')
```

This gives the output as i and j both have 0 value.

```
0 0
```

In programming language inner loop are completed first.
So following code will execute again

```
for j in range(2):
```

This will set value of j as 1

Now j is 1 and i is still 0
So output will look like

```
0 00 1
```

(Note: first 0 0 is the previous output)

Now the following code is finished

```
for j in range(2):
```

Its finished at j's value 1 because range(2) means value will start from 0 to 1.

Now the following code will execute.

```
for i in range(2):
```

and i value will become 1.

Now the inner loop will run again.

```
for j in range(2):
```

This will set value of j again 0 and in the next iteration 1.

So the final output looks like

```
0 00 11 01 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i = 0 and j = 0

it will print 0 0, here end is '', means no space

now i = 0 and j=1

it will print 0 00 1

now i=1 j=0

it will print 0 00 11 0

now i=1 and j=1

it will print 0 00 11 01 1

Answer (score 0):

Does this slight reformatting of your output help:

```
0 00 11 01 1   ==>  0 0 | 0 1 | 1 0 | 1 1
                    i j   i j   i j   i j
```

Comment: That actually clears things up pretty well. But I still have the problem of trying to understand why  the second time around it runs it isnt | 1 1 | instead of | 0 1 |

Comment: starting in the "i" loop, i is 0, then we do what is inside the "i" loop, which is the j loop, j starts at 0, and we do what is in the j loop which is the print, now we do the next step of the j loop, (j is 1) and the print.  Now the j loop is done, so back out to the i loop, i is 1, now we do the j-loop.. etc

Comment: Maybe it helps to think of the body of each loop as a black-box,  so the outside loop says I am going to do what is in my black box twice (once with i=0, once with i=1.  each time the black-box will complete whatever it does.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below and It will remove the confusion:

```
>>> for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print(i, j, sep='', end=' ')


00 01 10 11
```